# How do i make an if statement have multiple strings?

Tags: java

I an making a simple rock paper scissors game and I want to make a if statement there if the user enters in a word besides rock,paper,scissors it saya invalid choice, i tried "||" and i also tried "&&".

```
if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && ("Paper") &&  ("rock")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid choice. Ending program.");

    // Exit program
    Main.main(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") || userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") ||  userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")))
{
    System.out.println("Invalid choice. Ending program.");

    // Exit program
    Main.main(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection of correct choices and check if user choice is among them

```
List<String> correctChoices = Arrays.asList("rock","paper","scissors");
...

if (!correctChoice.contains(userChoice.toLowerCase()){
    //invalid input
}
```

To improve performance of `contains` method you can use HashSet instead of list

```
Set<String> correctChoices = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("rock","paper","scissors"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem:

```
if(!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
{
    System.out.println("Invalid choice. Ending program.");

    // Exit program
    Main.main(args);
}
```

Using `!String_name.equalsIgnoreCase(String s)` is the same as `!=` in case of comparing primitive data types, but you can't obviously use that on Strings, since by using `!=` you would just evaluate if they are not the same object, which would always be false.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") || userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") ||  userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid choice. Ending program.");

    // Exit program
    Main.main(args);
}
```

Your syntax of `&& ("Paper")` is invalid, only boolean types are allowed. What you want to check is that the choice does not equal "scissors" AND does not equal "paper" AND does not equal "rock".

Of course, it's not the only way since you can use negation binary logic to switch true with false and AND with OR.

Answer (score 0):

A concise approach is to use a `switch` statement.

```
switch( userChoice.toLowerCase() ) {
   case "scissors":
   case "paper":
   case "rock":
      // Continue
      break; 
   default:
      System.out.println("Invalid choice. Ending program.");
      System.exit(1);
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum Possibilities {
    ROCK,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS;

    public static boolean isInPossibilities(String input) {
        for (Possibilities possibilitie: values()) {
            if (possibilitie.name().equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Then do your check like this :

```
if(Possibilities.isInPossibilities("paper")) {
    ....
}
```

This was the solution for your specific code. But for the answer that fits the most to the title then you can use Porz answer.